# Bot is online but the prefix and commands don't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I try to put the prefix with the command the bot doesn't respond.

code:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField, Permsision } = require('discord.js');

const prefix ='>';

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot has come online.')
})
 
client.on('message', message => {
 
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
 
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'mc':
 
            if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send('You must type a minecraft server ip')
            if(!args[2]) return message.channel.send('You must type a minecraft server port')
 
            ping(args[1], parseInt(args[2]), (error, reponse) =>{
                if(error) throw error
                const Embed = new RichEmbed()
                .setTitle('Server Status')
                .addField('Server IP', reponse.host)
                .addField('Server Version', reponse.version)
                .addField('Online Players', reponse.onlinePlayers)
                .addField('Max Players', reponse.maxPlayers)
                
                message.channel.send(Embed)
            })
        
 
    }
 
})
```

I expected it to respond to me when I did the command, it showed in the console the bot was ready
and I searched about it and it said I needed intent and I think I have it.

Comment: Yes, there is no `message` event, but `messageCreate` so just change it to `client.on('messageCreate', message => {`

Answer (score 0):

As [`Zsolt Meszaros`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6126373) mentioned, the `message` event was deprecated in Discord.JS version 13 and replaced by `messageCreate` in version 14.

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField, Permsision } = require('discord.js');

const prefix = '>';

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot has come online.');
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'mc':
            if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send('You must type a minecraft server ip');
            if (!args[2]) return message.channel.send('You must type a minecraft server port');

            ping(args[1], parseInt(args[2]), (error, reponse) => {
                if (error) throw error;
                const Embed = new RichEmbed()
                    .setTitle('Server Status')
                    .addField('Server IP', reponse.host)
                    .addField('Server Version', reponse.version)
                    .addField('Online Players', reponse.onlinePlayers)
                    .addField('Max Players', reponse.maxPlayers);

                message.channel.send(Embed);
            });
    }
});
```